# URI redirect with only query parameters

Tags: url-redirection, owasp-top-ten

Is it possible to perform a URI redirect to a different domain if you only have raw write access to query parameters?

In pseudo-code, creation of the URI looks like this:

```
URI = "/example/path?" +
"thing1=" + rawFormValueFrom("#thing1") + 
"&thing2=" + rawFormValueFrom("#thing2")
```

I have two particular suspicions that I have to confirm:

### URI-delimiting characters

Would putting a an un-encoded space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, comma, semicolon, or some other character make the browser navigate to the second URI if one were provided? In other words, were the value of `#thing2` `https://security.stackexchange.com` (notice the leading space), would your typical browser navigate me to the second URI in the string?

### Backspacing

Would it be possible to supply raw backspace characters to a form input to make it erase parts of the URI behind it? In other words, if the value of #thing1 were `<backspace><backspace>3=actually2`, would the URI become `/example/path?thing3=actually2&thing2=...` ?

Comment: no, if you're stuck after the question mark, there's nothing you can say to change its mind...

Answer (score 1):

**No.** you cannot trick the browser into redirecting.

You can write a web page that [reads query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [redirects the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

But this is a stack overflow questions those are stack overflow answers.

If you do trick a browser into following a redirect like you describe, you should report it to the browser's security team to fix it.